# Bug in the site navigation links

Tags: bug, design, display

The main site looks like this on my system:

[image: Title bar of Mi Yodeya, with "Unanswered" directly below "Badges"]

Meta looks like:

[image: Title bar of Mi Yodeya Meta, with "Unanswered" directly below "Badges"]

Presumably, the Unanswered link should not be under Badges. I tested on Firefox (32.0) and Chrome (30.0.1599.114) both running on 64bit Debian Linux. Opera (12.16) on the other hand, worked as expected. Firefox's error console showed nothing.

I also made sure this was not an issue with zooming. Not only did this happen at the default zoom level but zooming out/in made no difference. The size changed but the positions of the elements did not.

Comment: How wide is your browser window?  From these screen shots it *looks* like that shouldn't be the problem, but SE sometimes does some messy things if you're below a certain higher-than-you'd-expect minimum width.  (I don't remember what it is exactly, but higher than 1024.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio maximized on my laptop (1600x900) and on my external screen (1440x900). Same thing happens when I extend the browser to take up the width of both screens. So no, looks like this is not the problem.

Comment: Hm, yeah, that should be plenty!  (I'm not seeing this Firefox and the monitor I'm using right now is only 1280 wide.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think [meta-tag:display] is more appropriate, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA oh, I didn't know we had that tag.  (Only 3 questions, so I think I'm not the only one. :-) )  Feel free to add it.  "Design" is used for other "this doesn't look right" bugs, so I don't think that's incorrect here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think of display as questions like this whereas design are more about changes to the _lechatchila_ picture,like a request for a new font or discussion about if we like the tree logo.

Comment: I get this on my 7-inch (Android) tablet using Chrome, but that wouldn't explain your problem.